# data validation dropdown only shown when msgbox appeared

Tags: .net, vb.net, vsto

This might sound weird

I just made a data validation in Excel,which I know is working. The incelldropdown not showing by default. But if I create a msgbox before the line, then the incelldropdown shown.

This is where the incelldropdown shown:

```
MsgBox("hello")
Me.Range("A6:A20").Validation.Add(Type:=Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, _
   AlertStyle:=Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, _
   [Operator]:=Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, Formula1:="=named_range1")
Me.Range("A6:A20").Validation.InCellDropdown = True
```

But if I remove the MsgBox, the incelldropdown not showing:

```
Me.Range("A6:A20").Validation.Add(Type:=Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, _
AlertStyle:=Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, _
   [Operator]:=Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, Formula1:="=named_range1")
Me.Range("A6:A20").Validation.InCellDropdown = True
```

Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks!